# Getting NoMethodError (undefined method) on every EXISTING properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I enter `movie = Movie.limit(1)` into the console, I get

```
SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]] => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Movie id: 2, title: "Superman", rating: "PG", total_gross: 0.134218018e9, created_at: "2019-02-20 07:42:18", updated_at: "2019-02-20 08:17:24", description: "Clark Kent grows up to be the greatest super-hero", released_on: "1978-12-15">]>
```

However, if I enter `movie.title`, instead of getting "Superman", I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):2
Movie Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for #<Movie::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055b334842668>)
```

Spent the last three hours hunting for the cause to no avail.

EDIT: My class has the method:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all
end
```

But when I call it from the index view, none of the properties work:

```
<% @movies.each do |f| %>
  f.title
<% end %>
```

ArgumentError in Movies#index

**UPDATE:** I had a blank row in my database returning nil for every property. Deleting this row fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying `limit` on an ApplicationRecord inherited class, you get an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, which is in other words, a collection (array) of different objects belonging to that specific model.

So, that explains the error you're getting, `title` isn't available as a method for a `Movie::ActiveRecord_Relation`, but it does for a Movie object, so still, you need an additional step to do, that is to access a specific record from the limit result.

```
movie = Movie.limit(1).first
```

That would work, that's rational if the limit is greater than 1, but you could also see [`take`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take) and/or [`first`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) (both also can receive the amount of records to query).

Comment: Thanks, this works in the console, but not in my controller class. It used to work at first, but it stopped working even when doing @movies = Movie.all

Comment: Are you sure there's a title column in the movies table? how're the migrations, all up?

Comment: Yes, all my migrations are up and not only do I have a title column, but I get the same error no matter which one I pick.

Comment: What about with a single record, using `first` or `last`? do you have the same behavior in the console as in the browser?

Comment: Thanks. I checked first and last and turns out I had an empty row that was returning nil on everything. I just deleted the row and everything work perfecly now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Even if this answer wasn't what helped you to keep your work, you can create your own explaining what you did, so for others your answer might be useful.